# it didn't work on visual studio 2010, why?? Object Reference not set to an Instance of an object

Tags: c#, object

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    try
    {
        Customer cust = (Customer)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        //MessageBox.Show("Birth Date: " + textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = cust.FirstName.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = cust.Number.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = cust.Email.ToString();
    }

   catch { }
 }
```

The error :

> Object Reference not set to an Instance of an object

Comment: How are you adding items to the ListBox?

Comment: First: remove `catch { }` from all code you ever write. Second, [learn to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Deselect the item and it goes boom.

And there is almost no excuse for catch {}.  The only case I've seen where it's at all sane is if reading a configuration file fails and you intend to continue with defaults if that happens.